# Quick methods to check perfect $4^{th}, 5^{th}, 6^{th}$ powers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

Are there any quick modulus methods to check if a number could be a perfect power (4, 5, 6)? Preferably binary methods that could be extended to higher powers.

For example, a perfect fourth power has to be $0, 1 \pmod{16}$ from a square number being $0, 1 \pmod 4$. Also, a perfect sixth power has to be $0,1 \pmod{8}$.

Other than something very simple, a few iterations of Newton's method converges very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I am copying [Jeremy Teitelbaum's answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/163090/).

---

See the paper by Bernstein, Lenstra, and Pila: “[Detecting Perfect Powers by Factoring into Coprimes](http://cr.yp.to/lineartime/powers2-20060914-ams.pdf)”, *Mathematics of Computation*, Volume 76, #257, January 2007, pp. 385–388.

From the abstract:

> This paper presents an algorithm that, given an integer $n>1$, finds the largest $k$ such that $n$ is a $k$th power.

The algorithm runs in time $\log(n)(\log\log(n))^{O(1)}$.

Comment: This is good, but I was looking for something simpler. Something that could be done just to reject obvious cases