# Determine if a number n is a power

Tags: radicals

What would be an efficient algorithm to determine if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ can be written as $n = a^b$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{N}, b>1$?

So far, I've tried:

```
def ispower(n):
    if n<=3:
        return False
    LIM = math.floor(math.log2(n))
    for b in range(2,LIM+1):
        a = math.pow(n, 1/b)
        a_floor = math.floor(a)
        print(a,a_floor)
        if a == a_floor:
            return True
    return False
```

That is, checking if the $b-th$ roots are integer, for $b$ from 2 to $LIM$, where $LIM$ stands for the ultimate limit of n being a power of 2.

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: How large might $n$ be? When using Python floating point numbers (i.e., with a decimal point), you cannot count on reliably accurate results, especially for large numbers. By contrast, working only with the int (integer) data type, you will have accurate results until you overflow your computer.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/163090/25554) cites a paper that gives a very efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If you restrict $b\geq 2$, then the most efficient way is *probably* simply testing each root $b = 2, 3, \ldots, \lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor$. This is of runtime $O(\log n)$ and can be implemented using the `gmpy2` module efficiently:

````
import gmpy2

p = 197
e = 989
n = p ** e

b = 2
while 2 ** b <= n:
    root, exact = gmpy2.iroot(n, b)
    if exact:
        print(f"n is a {b}-th power")
        break
    b += 1
else:
    print(f"n is not a perfect power.")
```
````

Comment: It's definitely not $O(\log n)$ because you can't extract a root in constant time.

Comment: @MJD My bad, I was referring to taking $O(\log n)$ roots. If we ignore the time complexity of multiplying large numbers then the algorithm is $O(\log^2 n)$ by binary search (I believe).

Comment: It's the same code, then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since $n = n^1$, every number can be written in the required form. Thus an efficient algorithm is to always answer yes.

Comment: The question has been changed, making my answer incorrect, but I answered to the original question.